# How to iterate through an associative array properly, when one of the keys is "1"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, key, associative-array

I have to create this Change Calculator that returns the amount of change you get back from a transaction and also returns the coins from the associative array below.

Unfortunately I can't iterate through the array properly (starting with the highest key 500:"$5") because it always starts with 1 penny (1:"1p") then 2 etc.

So for instance if the item costs $5, and I pay $5.75, instead of getting back 50p, 20p, 5p, coins, it's 1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p.

Thanks!

```
            var coins = {500:"$5", 200:"$2", 100: "$1", 50: "50p", 20:"20p", 10:"10p", 5:"5p", 2:"2p", 1:"1p"};
        $('#calc').click(function(){
            var priceVar = document.getElementById("price").value;
            var paidVar = document.getElementById("paid").value;                
            var result =  (paidVar - priceVar).toFixed(2);
            var paidCents = result * 100;
            var coinList = "";
                for(var key in coins) {
                    if (paidCents >= key) {
                        paidCents -= key;
                        coinList += coins[key];
                    }       
                }       
            $('#change').html("$"+result);
            $('#coins').html(coinList);});
```

Comment: can your array look like this `coins = [ {denom: "$5", value: 500}, {denom: "$2", value: 200} ...etc]` or does it have to be as you show it? If you can set it up as an array of objects you can iterate through them in order

Comment: One other thing I was wondering about- you use dollars and "p". Wouldnt it be dollars and cents "c"?

Comment: It has to be like that unfortunately :( and it used to be pounds signs instead of dollars but for some reason it shows it in a weird way in my browser. Probably a language pack issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var coins = {500:"$5", 200:"$2", 100: "$1", 50: "50p", 20:"20p", 10:"10p", 5:"5p", 2:"2p", 1:"1p"};
        $('#calc').click(function(){
            var priceVar = document.getElementById("price").value;
            var paidVar = document.getElementById("paid").value;                
            var result =  (paidVar - priceVar).toFixed(2);
            var paidCents = result * 100;
            var coinList = "";
while(paidCents > 0){
               for(var key in coins) { 
                    if (paidCents < key || key == '500') { 
if(key == '500' && paidCents >= key){ lasttry = key; }
                        paidCents -= lasttry; 
                        coinList += coins[lasttry]; break;
                    }   lasttry = key;    
                }       }
            $('#change').html("$"+result);
            $('#coins').html(coinList);});
```

Two things:
- Even though your object starts with 500, javascript will still turn it around and the lowest will be first when you loop through it.
- Also in your for loop it will only take one of each type of coin. So for 45, it will not take two times 20. That is why I had to use the while loop.

Comment: Just tested it, and for some reason when the price is for instance $4, and you paid $6.75, it gives back $5 of change in coins?

Comment: You are right, the '<' between paidCents and key in:( if(key == '500' && paidCents < key){ ) should be '>'. Sorry for that. Check it out now.

Comment: It worked for everything except when the change was $5. (It showed $2 $2 $1) so I added an extra if statement: if (paidCents == '500') {
        coinList += "$5"; 
        paidCents = 0;
        break;
      }